# Will an OS boot if I simply backup and restore all its files

Tags: restore, system-restore

Can I backup and restore an OS simply by copying and restoring all its files, *file by file*, rather than copying and restoring the disk partition, *byte by byte*? Consider:

If I have a booting OS on a hard drive, then:

1. Do a full backup of all the files, file by file (eg. `rsync -aP`)
2. Format the drive (with the same file system, boot manager, etc.)
3. Copy all the files back to the drive

When I turn on the machine with the drive in place, will my OS boot and work exactly like before?

Does Linux, macOS or Windows have crucial information not covered by file-by-file backup, eg.

1. Files that must reside in exact positions on the drive that would be lost in regular file copy
2. Partition data that cannot be re-created with your regular formatting software
3. Special hidden data such as proof of purchase of the OS or installed software

Comment: File backups do not include any boot sector information which is removed by a format.

Comment: You could backup the entire File System, which is different from backing up all files in a File System.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321: The objective of the question is to check possible precautions to doing a file-by-file backup and restore.

Comment: The comment cut off. What I meant was that if you back up the full file system, you can backup the boot sector, giving you a **FULL COPY** of the operating system, making it bootable.

Comment: If you mean like doing a `dd` / `dd_rescue` of the whole partition, then sure, I know about that. The question specifically asks what happens if you only copy files, for different OS-es. Rewrote to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

> **Can I backup and restore an OS simply by copying and restoring all its files, file by file**

In general, no.

Some examples

- software and data required for booting is normally stored, at least partly, outside the 
  reach of normal filesystem file-based I/O. For example you may not easily be able to read Master Boot Records (MBR) or UEFI partitions in the same way you access your programs and documents.
- Unix like operating systems tend to present everything as a file, but even so, copying a device file requires an abnormal process. The normal read process for a serial port yields data being transmitted to that port, it does not give you a representation of the on-disk data needed to recreate that device file.
- Your copying process needs to make special provision so that linked files (hard-links or soft-links) are not converted to multiple copies of the data.

Tools like rsync do have options to do the sort of file-based copying you discuss - but these tools have to make special provision for each of the special cases.

For example

- [rsync full system backup of Arch-Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rsync#Full_system_backup)

  # rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /path/to/backup/folder

Comment: Good advice from the Arch-Linux pages: "better than disk cloning since it allows for a different size, partition table and filesystem to be used, and (...) greater control over file (...) attributes". You mention "software and data required for booting", however that's not important as long as that data is just generic data that can be re-created during regular formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the OS, really. I'm going to assume Windows here, and in that case, you cannot.

The reason is that there's more going on than just files being present.

Windows requires the following to be present to work correctly: Every single file and folder it needs needs to be copied. This includes files to folders the user simply doesn't have rights to. But if you boot into a different environment, then you could potentially copy all files, including those you normally don't have rights to.

In addition, all file and folder permissions need to be in tact. Most copy programs don't also copy the ACL information. Breaking this will break windows.

Lastly and most importantly, Windows does work with symbolic links. When you perform a file copy, these links are never copied and requires special copy software to do that properly.

If you manage to do all this, then you should have a working windows installation.

But windows probably still won't boot from it, because the boot manager usually sits on a different partition, which you can't get access to, so that entire partition needs to be backupped.

If you actually manage to get that part also done correctly, then you can indeed do this. Do note, that all the time and effort you use to copy the files and make it work again, will be about 10 times more than that of using a partition backup, the very same thing you try to avoid.

And don't think you get an 1:1 copy of the partition with this software. The better backup solutions, such as Acronis will backup only the used space, not everything, including the empty space. This effectively means that it will be much faster and more secure to use partition backup software, than to try this yourself. And lastly, these partition backup software allow you to extract single files from the entire backup archive, which is probably what you are after anyway.

So long story short, its unlikely to work, but if you are a very capable person and you have loads of time, then yes, you may pull it off. But if you just use backup software, not only do you achieve the exact same thing (actually no, backup software also allows compression), but its much quicker too.

Answer (score -1):

most probably it won't boot. Apart from files you can see, there are many other information you need to backup, and these information may be hidden or located in other locations. You can use either Windows backup and restore feature or third party backup software to backup your system.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  The site is a solution knowledge base, so the intention is for each answer to provide a solution to the question that has not already been contributed.  This answer doesn't really add anything to the discussion.  It's great that you took the site tour.  Browse other answers that are upvoted or provided by high-rep users to get a feel for what the community values as a good answer.  There's also good general advice in the help topics if you click on the question mark in the top bar.